# Background-position, rule of thirds images, and mobile design

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I'm working with images that have been aligned with rule-of-thirds on the focus of the image, and `background-image` to put the image in the page.

When a user is on a tablet (or bigger) device, I'm using `background-position:50%;` which is fine; I don't mind that the picture is aligned off to the side.

However, on mobile devices, I would like the subject (which is on the right rule-of-third line -- see my JSBin for an example) to be horizontally centered on the screen. I know that I can use different percentages, such as `background-position:75% 50%` to get it close, but as the width of the device changes the 75% is no longer "center".

Is there a way, without writing a hundred different media queries so that it's always centered, to have `background-position` be dynamic enough to always center an image on mobile?

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xokunuguzo/edit?css,output) of what I'm looking at.

Some assumptions:

- Pictures will always be aligned on rule-of-thirds
- Pictures will always have the same physical dimension
- Work in IE9+
- Not worried about vertical alignment

Answer (score 0):

For smaller than 768px try:

```
background-position: -50vw;
```

And you may have to set the background size to 150% instead of cover for this case.

Comment: Thanks, that gets it pretty close! Take a look at the updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ciloqokudo/1/edit?css,output). The only issue now is that it stretches the image, whereas ideally it would just cut off the parts of the image that don't fit in.